# gnome app grid incomplete applcation names

Tags: gnome, interface, gsettings, desktop-apps

In the applications view, the app names are truncated. I can't seem to find a setting relating to this with gsettings or Google. All I found was "this issue was fixed in GNOME 40," although I am using the latest LTS with GNOME 42. Here's a picture of my problem:

[image]

As you can see, some of the apps are cut off by the "..." such as "Additional Drivers" and "Softwre & Updates."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gnome developers decided to leave the one line description for all of the icons. What has been implemented though, and that is the "fix" you refer to, is that hovering over the icon reveals the full name (e.g. see Chromium in the picture).

[image]

Comment: yeah i know about the hover thing, would have been ridiculous to not exist. sooo....im stuck with it huh